# Complex graphs and charts on React and React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, d3.js, raphael, antd

I will start a new project that will need customo charts and graphics. I will be building special trending, analytics and gantt charts for tons of data stored in the cloud.

In the past I've used D3/Raphael/Ant + JQuery, but now I'm moving to mobile and React. As far as I know, svg tas are DOM tags as HTML tags, so my first impression is that React will handle it normally. I've heard also about Tiny SVG, a subset of SVG for mobile, so here are my doubts:

a) Will React and React Native work fine with SVG ? Are there limitations on using it ?

b) What is supposed to be Tiny SVG spec launched in 2013 ?

c) In older browsers, normally SVG is not supported. In desktop app I've used Raphael with javascript, but what for React and React Native ?

d) Is D3 supported for React and React Native, for data manipulation ?

e) Is Raphael supported in React and React Native environments ?

f) Is Ant supported in React and React Native environments ?

g) How is the application performance, in case of a stack of D3, Raphael or Ant, React or React Native, specially on mobile environment ?

If there are best practices or desired stack to use for React or React Native I would love to hear.

Comment: SVG and React are unrelated things - it's not entirely clear what limitations you're imagining?

Answer (score 4):

a) Yes, React and React-native work very efficiently with SVG. React-Native has it's own ART library that you can import to create graphics but it is still under development.

b) In React and React Native, everything is a Component. So it wouldn't be a very good idea to use Tiny SVG.

c) There are a lot of possible options for generating SVG. You may import ART from react-native itself, but as I mentioned that it is still under development, what I prefer the most is 'react-native-svg'. Easy to use and a very well maintained package.

d) Yes, D3 is supported for both. But not the original D3 as it lacks the component system. You need to use [react-d3](https://github.com/react-d3) instead as it has implemented components. It is one of the most powerful and customizable libraries for manipulating charts from scratch. For implementation you can check out my react-native project [here](https://github.com/sahutkarsh/rolling-returns/tree/master/src/components) where I've used both reat-native-svg and react-d3.

e) react-raphael is available instead.

f) Yes Ant is supported. Take a look over 'Ant Design of React'.

g) Haven't used Raphael or Ant, but I can assure you that react-d3 works great in native environment!

Answer (score 0):

a) There are limitations. React Native uses react native art which cannot take in a normal svg like on the web. Furthermore the svgs that it can create are just views not scalable vectors like you are used to. There are libraries however that can compile complex svgs into the native views.

c) multiple solutions for svg in react native, the one I have seen is https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg.

d)d3js is not supported as it does not use native views. Rule of thumb is if it has ui that is web based it will not work with react native. If it is just javascript ie lodash it will work.

e) see d

g) In my experience svgs as they are have memory leaks in react native and this can cause performance issues. They may have fixed this in newer build. Latest I have used is .40